# Using multiple times appDelegate in the same UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers, nsinteger, appdelegate

I am new to objective-C and cocoa.

In my UIViewController I need to access AppDelegate multiple times in different methods

A. Is calling in every method:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

consumes more performance?

B. I tried to create a global parameter in the UIViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface Login_ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>{
  AppDelegate *appDelegate;
}
```

Implementation and usage:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  
     appDelegate.businessId = [businessId integerValue]; 
}

- (BOOL)credentialsValidated
{
     appDelegate.businessId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:BUSINESS_ID];
}
```

But I get warning (although the code works)

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *') from 'NSInteger' (aka 'int');
```

The declaration of businessId in appDelegate is:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property NSInteger *businessId;
```

and the implementation:

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize businessId;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `*` from your declaration in the app delegate:

```
@property NSInteger (assign) businessId;
```

`NSInteger` is a primitive, so you do not need an object pointer.

Comment: Thanks worked fine. but what about the first question? does it consume performance?

Comment: No penalty. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: what is the best coding practice?

Comment: This is a very common pattern. You could also define a text macro for faster typing, but it does not really make a big difference. Another popular and reasonable option for storing program-wide variables is `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1):

A. This won't give any performance penalty unless you call it 100000000 a second. BTW never assume smth - always measure. There is a tool called Time Profiler - use it to find all the bottlenecks.

B. NSInteger is just a typedef to int - it is POD type and not ObjC object, so you can't send messages to it. Use NSInteger instead of NSInteger*.

Answer (score 1):

You can define AppDelegate like this
       #define DELEGATE (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
       now you can use DELEGATE where you need..

Comment: You can this where you are using all constant declare make Global class or same class here also like this #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"   #define DELEGATE (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: thanks - but how do I use it in the code? I tried to import my constants class and write APP_DELEGATE.shouldDo but it wouldn't compile